# Events way of erasing you've no longer erase SONY SmartWatch2

Tags: sony, sony-smartwatch

Since not write only Japanese I'm using the google translation.

I have been the development of now SmartWatch2.

But trouble is that has happened.

Phenomenon occurs that would remain indelible events to Notification, the state in which it becomes not rid has often occurred.

Not react to touch events of SmartWatch2 time of this state, also it will even be ignored by issuing what Intent.

Many of occurrence opens the event on SmartWatch2, occurs when writing an event from the new smartphone in the state that are reading the text.

When it comes to this state will still remain as long as you do not want to reset the SmartWatch2.

NotificationUtil.deleteAllEvents (mContext);

Please tell me the software method to turn off the remaining I events in.

Thank you.

Comment: The return value of NotificationUtil.deleteAllEvents is 0, but there are still three on Smartwatch2.

Comment: http://ja.stackoverflow.com/ ?

Comment: ja.stackoverflow.com is not tag sony-smartwatch

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, since the Google Translate from Japanese -> English is often very difficult to understand, you are asking why NotificationUtil.deleteAllEvents() is not removing all of the notification events being shown on the watch?

Are you trying to remove only notifications generated by your extension or all notifications?  The problem may be that the API will only remove events generated by your extension, you cannot remove events from other apps.  See the reference for more info:

http://developer.sonymobile.com/reference/sony-addon-sdk/com/sonyericsson/extras/liveware/extension/util/notification/NotificationUtil#deleteAllEvents(Context)

Comment: Reply Thank you.<p>
English is difficult. But thanks to that you will read even a little.<p>
私はあなたが示してくれたLinkを読みましたが、答えは書かれていませんでした。<p>
他のアプリが作成したものではなく、私がaddEventで登録したものが残ってしまっているのです。<p>
試して下さい。addEventで数個追加した後、そのひとつをSmartWatch2で読みます。その状態でdeleteAllEventsを発行してみてください。<p>
多くは完全に削除されますが、私の経験上10回に1回イベントが残ってしまいます。<p>
重要なのはSmartWatch2で読んでいる状態の時にdeleteAllEventsが発生するとイベントを削除しきれない様子です。<p>
日本人スタッフがいることを願います。

Comment: Reporting of details.
Additional normally in AddEvent.
The shutdown the SmartWatch2.
I'll add in AddEvent.
Launch the Smartwatch2.
First registered event will not disappear.
Or in this case SmartWatch2 does not disappear except re-initialization event?
I was on to confirm that they are connected SmartWatch2 prior to the AddEvent.

Comment: Hello Marlin, I confirm there is a problem of removing notifications with NotificationUtil.deleteAllEvents. I have been waiting a long time for resolution from Sony. And 110,000 disappointed users of my app

Answer (score -1):

Users of my app claim that only unread notifications can be deleted. Read ones still remain after notificationUtil.deleteAllEvents